# How to call Alexa intent from external python code and alexa device to announce

Tags: python, api, response, external, alexa-skills-kit

Here is my requirement.

1. External program will get some signals from subprograms each min or specific intervals.
2. I want that external program to call Alexa and pass this information
3. who connect with this skill set should hear automatically this output rather than asking Alexa what is the status

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with Alexa. Alexa can be activated only using the voice and it's by design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with Alexa for business. It's not supported for my aws region, but I guess it's for a few US regions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/a4b/latest/ag/announcements.html